# JS - Async Await - second function doesn't wait for first function to complete, then first function executes again

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await

I'm trying to use `async await` in `Angular 10`to first load a list of users from my backend database (Spring Boot with MariaDB) with an http request and then, after the list is loaded, to filter that list for one specific user.
But somehow the `loadUsers()` keeps getting executed twice, as you can see in the resulting log at the end of my post.

Here's how I'd expect my code to work:

1. load all users -> console.log the list of all my users (a)
2. filter the users list and then console.log this one filtered user -> (b)

But instead of a) -> b), I get a) -> b) -> a). Where first a) is empty, because the http request wasn't finished yet, then b) which is therefore also empty, since the users are not loaded yet, and then again a), after the users were loaded?

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.loadOwner();
}

loadOwner = async () => {
  const result = await this.loadUsers()  // I'm not doing anything with the result, maybe that's the reason?
  // do something else here after users loading completes
  this.user= this.users.filter(user => user.id === this.product.userId)[0]  
  console.log("The user: " + this.user)  // b) (should get logged as last)
}

loadUsers() {
this._update.currentUsers$.subscribe(users => {
    this.users = users;
    console.log("my users: " + this.users)  // a) (should get logged first)
})
}
```

This is the final log that I'm getting with a) -> b) -> a) structure:

[image: result]

The filtering and the http request are working, I had the expected end result already but wanted to have cleaner code with async await, instead of nesting the loadUser function into the subscribe scope of the loadUsers. There are other things that I have to do after this and it gets more and more nested.

Comment: `loadUsers()` doesn't return a `Promise`

Comment: From the code you are showing above, it is unclear why your `loadUsers` is getting called multiple times. `loadUsers` doesn't return a `Promise` and `loadOwner` calls `loadUsers`, but doesn't do anything with `result`. A more complete example would help diagnose the problem(s) you are facing.

Comment: Not sure why you don’t simply use observables for this. Async/await and promises in general are really not needed if you have rxjs available anyway..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to make your loadUsers() a Promise.

In Typescript:

```
loadUsers(): Promise<any> {
  // some code
  return Promise.resolve(true);
}
```

Actually, in your case you will have another problem since you should actually await on the `subscribe` in your loadUsers(). You can therefore do it like so:

```
async loadUsers(): Promise<any> {
  return this._update.currentUsers$.toPromise();
}
```

And await the loadUsers() when calling it.

Comment: An `Observable` has a method on it `.toPromise()`. That should be used instead

Comment: Await a `Promise` that resolves with `true` to only quash that value and then return a new already resolved promise? o.O

Comment: @Andreas indeed, there is much to be changed haha just to give OP a sense of what's happening there.